# Replace dynamic string with Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I'm using Visual Basic .NET and I'm trying to download a string of HTML, and I want to replace this

```
    id="dynamicstring"
```

With

```
    id="replacement"
```

The dynamicstring can be anything, that's why I'm having trouble replacing it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so please supply some code.

Comment: Dim Method As New Regex("<div.*</div>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)




Method.Matches(HTML_Source)(0).ToString

Comment: What does the HTML complete div line look like?

Comment: <div id="user01415">some crap</div>

Comment: That did not work, I got an error message about using too many )'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the content of the id attribute with this pattern:

```
(?<=<div\b(?>[^i]+|\Bi|i(?!d\s*=))*id\s*=\s*")[^"]+
```

details:

```
(?<=                 # open a look behind assertion (it's just a check
                     # nothing is matched inside it)
    <div\b           # div tag
    (?>              # atomic group (all the content until the id attribute
        [^i]+        # all that is not a "i"
      |              # OR
        \Bi          # a "i" not preceded by a word boundary
      |              # OR
        i(?!d\s*=)   # a "i" (with an implicite word boundary) 
                     # not followed by "d="
    )*               # close the atomic group and repeat as necessary
    id\s*=\s*"       # the id attribute until the first double quote
)                    # close the lookbehind
[^"]+                # content of the id attribute
                     # (all that is not a double quote)
```

Comment: And if I want to do this on a form like this: <form method="whatever" action="http://whatever.com/submit.php">inputs and such</form> and replace the string content of "action" how would I go about?

Comment: @user2230481: you can proceed in the same manner. But IMO a DOM parser will be more appropriate in the two situations.

Comment: Could you provide an example?